# Is w value unique to each vertex in perspective projection calculation?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

[image]

I know it may sound weird , but I'm really figuring about a question that w should be unique according to x , as perspective projection calculates w = x/d , where x stands for each vertex's location , while d stays unchanged because it's the distance from the near plane (projected screen) to the focus point. W are changed according to the distance .

So each vertex may has its own unique x value , but I'm not sure about it .Skew Transformation returns how far a vertex should move , multiplied by the factor w . That's the problem . I don't know how and where to store these too many variant w in one single matrix , or there're a lot of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

May be... you are talking about this matrix in homogeneous coordinate?

```
[   1   0   0   0 ]
[   0   1   0   0 ]
[   0   0   1   0 ]
[   0   0 1/d   0 ]
```

Multiplying this matrix (from left side) to the vector `[a b x 1]^T` becomes `[a b x w=x/d]^T`.
And the result 3D vector is `[a/w b/w x/w]^T` = `[a*d/x b*d/x d]^T`.

Comment: Oh . Thanks . I thought it were still in identity matrix format . In this case w is converted into z/d .

Comment: (So, something solved?)
In this formula, the value w itself is not included in matrix.
Value of w is just calculated as the 4th element, for each vertex.
So, it can be said as "Our work can not be completed by only multiplying the matrix. we must do the additional division by individual w value for each vertex".