# How to clip off '-w < x , y , z < w ' area in perspective projection culling calculation?

Tags: math, graphics, camera

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html
In this article it's said

> The clip coordinates, xc, yc and zc are tested by comparing with wc. If any clip coordinate is less than -wc, or greater than wc, then the vertex will be discarded.

But I see in glm there's already provided

```
glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)width/(float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f); //FOV , ratio , close , far
```

Where I think the preserved proportion can be calculated out by far plane's length and width deduced from the FOV angle, distance and ratio. [image]

So what does w do here ? Clipping can be done without w .

And there's another problem that if we're going to clip using w ,the result is against the aforementioned function format. I don't know where I was wrong . This is my process and if you can please help me .

Vertices outside w would be cut off . -w < o < w equals -1 < o/w < 1 equals -1 < r < 1 .
When o = w , o = x/d . Then tan(angle) = o/x = 1/d . Then r = 1 .

In this case , this 'tan(angle) = 1/d' requires the close plane to be in consistent with the FOV , while the fact is that we can arbitrarily set close plane value . [image]

Close plane should be independent . I have no idea how comes the conclusion that it must match the angle .

I think my process is not wrong , as the FOV-distance one's tan(angle) = borderlimit / x ,where borderlimit = w , and tan(angle) = 1/d , just as the same as the aforementioned result .

(My last post may be relevant [Is w value unique to each vertex in perspective projection calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992371/is-w-value-unique-to-each-vertex-in-perspective-projection-calculation/75992562#75992562)  )